# How to password-less log on via ssh alias

Tags: ssh, password

Suppose I have access to `pc` via a `server`. I can directly log-on to `pc` by using [How do I connect to a pc through another pc using ssh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2028/how-do-i-connect-to-a-pc-through-another-pc-using-ssh)

Such that my `.ssh/config` looks like:

```
Host short
Hostname pc
User me
ProxyCommand ssh me@server nc %h %p
```

The user and home-folder on `pc` and `server` are the same, but only `server` can be directly reached from the outside world. Now, if I `ssh short`, I have to type the same password twice.

I am now looking for a way to login using the tunnel without typing my password even once.

I've tried the `ssh-keygen` procedure, but that does not help me here. I also found this quite related question: [Set up password-less SSH tunneling from home computer behind NAT to inside computer behind gateway](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13896/set-up-password-less-ssh-tunneling-from-home-computer-behind-nat-to-inside-compu), but I can't figure out how this would apply to my situation.

The question basically comes down to: how can I setup passwordless login over a ssh alias?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set up key authentication on both machines, both the rebound machine (`server`) and the target machine (`pc`).

Create a key pair on your client machine (`ssh-keygen`) if you haven't already done so. Then copy the public key to `server` and add it to the authorization list. Then do the same thing for `pc`.

```
ssh-copy-id server
ssh-copy-id short
```

To avoid having to type your passphrase twice, run a key agent. Many systems are set up to run one when you log in: check if the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` environment variable is set. If it isn't, run `ssh-agent` as part of your session startup. Before you start using ssh in a login session, record your passphrase in the agent by running `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`.

Comment: In the second `ssh-copy-id`, I had to the name of the alias, which in the above example was `short`. Thanks!